# WPF Bind position of dragable items on a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have the following setup:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:Node>
            </local:Node>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I found that simply binding the properties `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` on the Node to their `Position` does not actually position them on the Canvas, because they are wrapped into a `ContentPresenter` like this:

```
ItemsPresenter
    |--Canvas
           |--ContentPresenter
                  |---Node
```

How would I fix this?

---

I thought about using `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` to style the `ContentPresenter` but I can't figure out how to bind the `ContentPresenter`'s properties to the `Node`'s position.

For completeness `local:Node` is roughly the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.Node"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseDown" 
             PreviewMouseMove="OnMouseMove">
    <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
</UserControl>
```

with the following code behind it:

```
public partial class Node : UserControl
{
    #region Position
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Position", typeof(Point), typeof(Node));

    public Point Position
    {
        get { return (Point) GetValue(PositionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PositionProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion Position

    public Node()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Implementation skipped for brevity, together with OnMouseMove this controls Position
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Implementation skipped for brevity
    }
}
```

Comment: I considered a [proposed duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332278/convert-shape-into-reusable-geometry-in-wpf/28338925?s=13|0.0000#28338925) that isn't stated nearly as directly as you have here and so I didn't actually vote to close yet, but the basic answer is the same (or at least, one option): instead of trying to bind to `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`, bind to a `TranslateTransform` object used for the `RenderTransform`. If you find the Q&A applicable here, you can vote-to-close yourself using the "Duplicate" option with that post.

Comment: I found a different question that is a lot more obvious identical to your own. See marked duplicate for an example of using the `ItemContainerStyle` to bind your model properties to the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties.

Comment: @PeterDuniho the duplicate you found use data in the DataContext as source properties of their bindings. I use the DataContext for something different and have the source properties on the local:Node. That's why their solution is not applicable to my problem, at least not as far as I can see that

Comment: the first proposed duplicate fits better